# xCode 6.1 toolbar bug or operator error?

Tags: toolbar, xcode6.1

I recently upgraded to Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d) and OS X Yosemite version 10.10 (14A389). Following the upgrade the Xcode development environment toolbar changed and the icons for the Assistant editor etc disappeared. I can still access the assistant editor via the view. I have spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to figure this out so any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

control+click or right click on titlebar and select show toolbar.